# Sorting a list of strings that contains hex value

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting, hex

I have a list of strings type that contains hex values, and the values are not the same length. hence the List can have FA1 and FA and F9F as values in the list, depends on user input, I was wondering what is the best way to sort this.

so the problem is the order of this list after sorted will be FA1,FA,F9F when it should be FA1,F9F,FA.

Comment: what you have tried  so far

Comment: Create a custom Comparator that compares length first and then alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may sort the list and pass a custom comparison function, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx

That function can convert hex strings to regular integers and compare these integers. Conversion can be done with help of `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32("FF1", 16);
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx

Could be something like this:

```
list.Sort(delegate(string lhs, string rhs)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(lhs, 16);
    int m = Convert.ToInt32(rhs, 16);
    return (n > m) ? -1 : (n < m) ? +1 : 0;
});
```

or (see @AlexR's remark) just

```
list.Sort(delegate(string lhs, string rhs)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(rhs, 16) - Convert.ToInt32(lhs, 16);
});
```

Comment: That's unnecessary parsing overload since the comparison by length and then lexicographically yields the same order but requires no parsing.

Comment: And a `return m-n;` will have the same effect and be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AlexR I used this code to solve the Problem.

```
ListOfString.Sort(delegate(string temp1, string temp2)
{        
     if (temp1.Length > temp2.Length) return 1;
     else if (temp1.Length < temp2.Length) return -1;                            
     return temp1.CompareTo(temp2);
});
```

if you want it to be descending simply do this

```
ListOfString.Sort(delegate(string temp1, string temp2)
{        
     if (temp1.Length < temp2.Length) return 1;
     else if (temp1.Length > temp2.Length) return -1;                            
     return temp1.CompareTo(temp2) * -1;
});
```

Comment: How does it work for numbers like `"09","100","0009"` ?

Comment: I don't think it will but for me the zeros are filtered out in another part of my program.

Comment: @user3813249 I have come up with a little check to allow such cases as well (see my answer).

Answer (score -2):

Complementary to my comment, a comparison code would look like this:

```
int compare(string a, string b) {
    if (a.StartsWith("0")) // Short circuit if RegEx won't do anything
        a = Regex.Replace(a, "^0+", ""); // RegEx replacement of all leading 0's by ""
    if (b.StartsWith("0"))
        b = Regex.Replace(b, "^0+", "");
    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return a.Length - b.Length; // < 0 for a < b, > 0 for a > b
    else
        return a.CompareTo(b);
}
```

Please don't bite me on syntax, I haven't coded in C# for a while since at work we use Java.

Comment: That's a nice downvoting bevaiour then. Thanks for the hint, I'll adress it.

Comment: what is `replaceAll`? `compareTo` or `CompareTo`?

Comment: `Okay does the code work now`? I didn't test it but I am sure `startsWith` will fail. It is `StartsWith` :)

Comment: @And regarding your very first comment, Is this answer better than just simply converting the string to int. (Shorter? faster? more readable?)

Comment: If we can short-circuit (i.e. have no leading `0`s) I still think it should perform better (I have seen the source code behind such base conversions, it's rather slow).

Comment: And yet another downvoter who didn't comment... I won't be posting on this tag anymore.

Comment: @AlexR A minor remark. It seems that sort is done in ascending order, while PO wants descending.